# Variables bound by two quantifiers and quantifers binding non-existent variables

Tags: predicate-logic

Just wondering if these formulae are valid in classical logic:

1. $\forall x \exists x (Px) \leftrightarrow \exists x (Px)$
2. $\exists x \forall x (Px) \leftrightarrow \forall x (Px)$
3. $\forall x (Py) \leftrightarrow Py$
4. $\exists x (Py) \leftrightarrow Py$

I 'm a beginner (using Suppes'*Introduction to Logic*). Couldn't find any sources on this. Thanks!

Comment: $\forall x \exists x: (P(x))$  isn't a valid expression at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See in Patrick Suppes, [Introduction to Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486406873) (1957 - Dover reprint), the recursive definition of *formulas* [page 52] :

> (a) Every atomic formula is a formula.
>
> [...]
>
> (d) If $R$ is a formula and $v$ is a variable then $(v)R$ and $(\exists v)R$ are formulas.

Thus, according to the syntax, $Px$ is an atomic formula; so $(∃x)Px$ is a formula, and also $(x)(∃x)Px$ [i.e. $∀x∃x(Px)$] is a formula.

Now for the "meaning": of course quantifying a variable which is not present in a formula does nothing.

In formula $∃x(Px)$ there are **no** a *free* variable $x$; thus the "meaning" of $∀x∃x(Px)$ is exactly $∃x(Px)$.

How to prove it ? See **BASIC RULES OF INFERENCE**, page 99.

*(a)* Start with $∀x∃x(Px)$ and apply **US** :

> from $∀xS$, derive $S(t)$, provided that no free occurrence of $x$ within scope of quantifier using variable of $t$ [i.e. we have to avoid that the *term* $t$, if containing a variable $y$, will be "captured" by a quantifier $\forall y$ or $\exists y$ already present into $S$].

In our case, $∃x(Px)$ has no free occurrences of $x$; thus, applying **US** we simply obtain $∃x(Px)$.

Thus, by **Rule C.P** [page 29] we may conclude with :

> > $∀x∃x(Px) \rightarrow ∃x(Px)$.

*(b)* Now consider $∃x(Px)$ and apply **UG** :

> from $S$ derive $∀xS$, provided that $x$ is not *flagged*.

In our case, $∃x(Px)$ has no free occurrences of $x$; thus, $x$ is not flagged and we may apply **UG** to obtain $∀x∃x(Px)$.

Again by **Rule C.P** :

> > $∃x(Px) \rightarrow ∀x∃x(Px)$.

Finally, apply the definition of $\leftrightarrow$ to conclude with :

> $∀x∃x(Px) \leftrightarrow ∃x(Px)$.

---

*Note*

The same approach, using the "existential" rules, applies to : $∃x∀x(Px)↔∀x(Px)$.

Comment: Thank you for the very useful answer. Additionally, I was under the impression that $P(y)$ means that $y$ is the only free variable used in $P$. I guess it can have other free variables too? Suppes doesn't seem to talk about this (at least not yet, and I'm at pg 93). If there are other free variables in $P$ (say $x$ and $z$), why only point out $y$? Why not all free variables in $P$ i.e. write $P(x,y,z)$ instead of $P(y)$?

Comment: @VijayKonnur - we need a distiction: if $P$ is a predicate letter, it has its own *arity*, i.e.the number of argument-places. In this case we have always to indicate them; thus, for binary (arity=2)predicate $P$ we have to write the (atomic) formulae $P(x,y)$ or $P(t_1,t_2)$. For formulae, using meta-variables, like $\varphi$ (it is **not** part of the formal language, bur part of the math-english used to speak of the formal languag and stands for a "generic" formula) the convention is that writing $\varphi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ we mean that free variables of $\varphi$ are *among* $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.

Comment: Ok makes sense. We're not talking about a any particular predicate P but a generic formula of the meta language. It would have been more appropriate to use phi etc. I guess. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @VijayKonnur - You are right ... but you must take into account that Suppes' book is quite hold, prior to LaTex and word-processors ... Thus, there is a typographical distinction between *predicate letters*, like $R$ (see page 45) and meta-variables for fomulae, like (bold) **R** (see page 52); the problem is that the difference is not so apparent like changing font (latin vs greek).